# Creating clusters directly from a GeoJSON APIRest response in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers, geojson, clustering

I am using OpenLayers latest version. Using a APIRest, I fetch a PostGIS endpoint and get a response in GeoJSON format.

Then this is used to create a source and a layer :

```
....
const response = await myfetch.json()
const opeGeoJsonFormat = new GeoJSON({
 dataProjection: "EPSG:2154",
 featureProjection: "EPSG:3857",
})
...
const ope = opeGeoJsonFormat.readFeatures(response)

const opeSource = new VectorSource({
  features: ope,
})

opeCouche = new VectorLayer({
  source: opeSource,
  style: styleOpeCouche,
  title: "opérations",
})
```

From the response, I would like to create clusters. Here is what I have done :

```
 const featuresPoint = []
 ope.forEach(operation => {
  const coordOpeTableau = operation.getGeometry().flatCoordinates
  const polygon = new Polygon(
    coordOpeTableau,
    "XY",
    coordOpeTableau.length - 1
  )
  const pointInterieur = polygon.getInteriorPoint()
  featuresPoint.push(new Feature(pointInterieur))
})
```

Then I have created a cluster source and a layer. So far so good.

I wonder if there is a way of creating the clusters points without using `new Polygon` class, since the geometries returned by the response are multipolygon?
I can't do it actually, but I am not an expert developer.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to get centroid of multipolygon geometry?

Comment: yes, and I wonder if it is possile without tjhe step of `new Polygon` but directly from ope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to get centroid directly from GeoJSON feature seems to be to use [turf.js](https://turfjs.org/) library and it's `turf.centroid` method.

Relevant part of the code would then be (assuming data is in `EPSG:4326` and features are in `EPSG:3857` CRS):

```
const formatGeoJSON = new ol.format.GeoJSON({
  dataProjection:'EPSG:4326',
  featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
});
var featuresPoint = [];

turf.featureEach(response, function(feature) {
  const centroid = turf.centroid(feature);
  const pointFeature = formatGeoJSON.readFeature(centroid);
  featuresPoint.push(pointFeature);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try asap and will be back.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I just notice that response is json although the [doc](https://turfjs.org/docs/#featureEach) says that the first argument has to be a GeoJSON.